# Ubuntu 12.04 apache server error

Tags: server, apache2

I have ubuntu `12.04 with apache`. The localhost was working fine. But today I wanted to setup a virtual host. After setting virtual host I just made restart server by doing this command sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart it showed me error like

```
    apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/testsite.com: No such file or directory
    Action 'configtest' failed.

The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I don't know whats the error I have tried to solve the error by going through google. But I can't solve this.

Here is the default file for apache2 configuration located in (/etc/apache2/sites-available)

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Now when I am opening localhost on my browser then it is showing `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost`

Comment: Sorry by why do you add the default file from sites-enabled when it is "line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"  that is complaning about "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/testsite.com" and a "testconfig" option? I would believe those to be more interesting?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove the what appears to be a bogus link from your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled file.

You can do this with:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/testsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the site (sudo a2dissite testsite.com), then restart apache, then enable the site (sudo a2ensite testsite.com), and restart again. (sudo service apache2 restart)